# Android "make fullbuild" failed: "Too many words (6306). Stop."

Tags: android, makefile

These days I faced make problem when I try to build android 4.1.
When I execute "make fullbuild", it will print below logs and stop unexpected.
But it will success if I "make libstagefright" and other modules.
Then I found when the make module related to java, it will failed.

Does anyone face same problem before?
Thanks.

...

```
Import includes file: out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libpng_intermediates/import_includes
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/png.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngerror.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pnggccrd.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngget.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngmem.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngpread.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngread.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngrio.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngrtran.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngrutil.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngset.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngtrans.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngvcrd.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngwio.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngwrite.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngwtran.c
host C: libpng <= external/libpng/pngwutil.c
host StaticLib: libpng (out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libpng_intermediates/libpng.a)
Export includes file: frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/export_includes
host Executable: aapt (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/aapt)
true
Notice file: frameworks/base/tools/aapt/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//bin/aapt.txt
Notice file: frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libandroidfw.a.txt
Notice file: frameworks/native/libs/utils/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libutils.a.txt
Notice file: system/core/liblog/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/liblog.a.txt
Notice file: system/core/libcutils/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libcutils.a.txt
Notice file: external/expat/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libexpat.a.txt
Notice file: external/libpng/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libpng.a.txt
Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt
build/core/java_library.mk:67: *** Too many words (6306).  Stop.
```